# Replace varying text in between <eb:PartyId></eb:PartyId>

Tags: text, replace, notepad++

How can I make the change with Notepad++?

```
    <eb:PartyId>Surename Secondname Firstname</eb:PartyId>
```

should be

```
    <eb:PartyId>PRINT</eb:PartyId>
```

The difficult thing for me is that the name section varies. I have tried several ways have not managed to find how this should be done.

Comment: There is a regular expression search mode in notepadd++, use that.

Comment: Just to clarify: I have more than 400 rows of that particular line in a file, all of which have different names in the Surename Secondname Firstname- part.

Comment: Yes, that's what a regular expression is for :)

Comment: Thanks Scott. What commands should I use in Find what and Replace with -fields in order to make the change?

Answer (score 0):

Try a regex find/replace in notepad++, like so:

```
Find: <eb:PartyId>.*.</eb:PartyId>
Replace: <eb:PartyId>PRINT</eb:PartyId>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ you can do it easily using regular expressions. First of all, make sure that your N++ version is the latest 6.5.1, or at least >= 6.0, and then go to `Search > Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   (<eb:PartyId>)[^<]+(<\/eb:PartyId>)(?!.+<\/eb:From>)
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   $1PRINT$2
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression" & check ". matches newline"
4. Then press `Replace All`

This will convert the following data:

```
<eb:From>
    <eb:PartyId>Surename Secondname Firstname</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:PartyId>Surename Secondname Firstname</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:PartyId>Surename Secondname Firstname</eb:PartyId>
</eb:From>
<eb:To>
    <eb:PartyId>Surename Secondname Firstname</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:PartyId>Surename Secondname Firstname</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:PartyId>Surename Secondname Firstname</eb:PartyId>
</eb:To>
```

To:

```
<eb:From>
    <eb:PartyId>Surename Secondname Firstname</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:PartyId>Surename Secondname Firstname</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:PartyId>Surename Secondname Firstname</eb:PartyId>
</eb:From>
<eb:To>
    <eb:PartyId>PRINT</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:PartyId>PRINT</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:PartyId>PRINT</eb:PartyId>
</eb:To>
```

Comment: Thanks again. The problem seems to be that I should also be able to define that the replacement should only happen inside <eb:To></eb:To> tags: the file has lines with similar tags inside <eb:From></eb:From> tags, which should remain as they are.

Comment: Please edit your original question and post a sample of your data, because the way that your `From` and `To` tags are ordered, affect the solution. I've updated my answer, but can't be sure if it will work for you until you show us a sample!